# MAAS deploy is stuck at iscsistart connect to no route :3260 failed no route to host

Tags: networking, server, juju, maas, openstack

While trying to deploy OS on nodes, MAAS deploy is repeatedly stuck at *iscsistart connect to no route :3260 failed no route to host*
Please see attached image for reference. How to resolve this issue?
[image]

Comment: Is 172.16.10.10 the correct IP address for your maas-rack-controller?